# Changing user name after comments were added in Word 2016 Mac

Tags: microsoft-word, osx-el-capitan

I have made some comments in the word file I'm working on. However, I realized that my user name was listed as "Microsoft Office User". I changed this to my own name, but the comments are still listed as "Microsoft Office User". Is there any way to make my name show up on the old comments?

Word version 15.16, on El Capitan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there any way to make my name show up on the old comments?

> When a comment is created, it is added to the Comments collection, which can be accessed through VBA. Each comment has Author and Initial properties that, respectively, represent the comment author's name and initials. The following macro is an example of how these can be changed:

```
Sub ChangeCommentAuthor()
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim sAuthorname As String
    Dim sInitial As String

    If Selection.Comments.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No comments in your selection!", _
          vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Cannot perform action"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    sAuthorname = InputBox("New author name?", _
      "Comments Author Name")
    If sAuthorname = "" Then End

    sInitial = InputBox("New author initials?", _
      "Comments Initials")
    If sInitial = "" Then End

    With Selection
        For J = 1 To .Comments.Count
            .Comments(J).Author = sAuthorname
            .Comments(J).Initial = sInitial
        Next J
    End With
End Sub
```

> 1. Make a selection that contains the comment you want to modify (select the text in the main document that includes the comment
>      indicator)
> 2. Run the macro.
> 3. Enter a new name and initials when prompted.
> 4. When the macro is done running, it may not appear like anything has changed.
> 5. If you save your document and reload it, you'll note that the comment author names have been changed as you indicated.

Source [Changing the User Name in Existing Comments](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T008614_Changing_the_User_Name_in_Existing_Comments.html)